# How can I write a WebSocket client in Julia?

Tags: websocket, julia

I would like to connect to a WebSocket via Julia. I attempted to get an echo response from `wss://echo.websocket.org`, but it does not seem to respond as I would have expected it to. Interestingly, it does seem to connect, though, whereas an invalid address will not.

```
julia> client = connect("echo.websocket.org", 443)
TCPSocket(open, 0 bytes waiting)

julia> println(client, "Hello, world!")

julia> readline(client)
""
```

Is it possible to accomplish this?

Comment: Web sockets have a particular [handshake and protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Protocol_handshake); it's not just an echo HTTP server. That's why your `println` won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web socket clients cannot be implemented by opening a socket and reading and writing directly to it. There is a reasonably complicated protocol that needs to be implemented. Further, a websocket client is meant to receive push request, and hence needs some way to handle them asynchronously.

There is a websocket client library implemented in Julia:  https://github.com/dandeliondeathray/DandelionWebSockets.jl

To install it, do: `Pkg.clone("https://github.com/dandeliondeathray/DandelionWebSockets.jl")`

To use it involves defining event handlers for network events.  Please see here for an example using echo: https://github.com/dandeliondeathray/DandelionWebSockets.jl/blob/b23307f360ef0b62e3064c6b1484599eb660f63f/examples/echo.jl

Answer (score 3):

There is now a specific library https://github.com/JuliaWeb/WebSockets.jl. Examples of how to use it are provided in examples/chat.jl and examples/chat-client.html.